# Kml rendering restrictions

Tags: google-maps, kml

Does anybody know what mean the following restrictions for rendering kmls on google maps?

```
"Maximum number of total document-wide features"
```

What is a feature for a kml? event click?

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A feature in KML is a term that refers to items like placemarks, folders, overlays and a few less frequent types. (See the object hierarchy [here](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html))

Currently the following limits apply for google maps:

> Note: these limits are temporary and are subject to change at any
>   time.
>
> - Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ) --> 3MB
> - Maximum uncompressed KML file size --> 10MB
> - Maximum number of Network Links --> 10
> - **Maximum number of total document-wide features --> 1,000**